# Unable to connect two devices via bluetooth for chat application

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am trying to implement a Bluetooth chatting application.
The app shows a list of paired devices, from which you can select a device and the app redirects to a ChatActivity. When this activity is started, the app should search for the selected device and connect to it.

When I install the apk on two devices and try connecting them together, it does not work.
The devices are discoverable and they are withing connection range. The app fails to make a socket connection between the two devices. 
The ChatService code is taken from the samples in sdk.

My code is :

### BTChatService.java

```
public class BTChatService {


private static final String TAG = "BTChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;
        private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BTListDeviceSecure";
        private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BTListDeviceInsecure";


        private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
        private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");


        private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
        private final Handler mHandler;
        private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
        private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
        private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
        private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
        private int mState;


        public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
        public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

        public BTChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
            mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            mState = STATE_NONE;
            mHandler = handler;
        }

        private synchronized void setState(int state) {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
            mState = state;


            mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
        }


        public synchronized int getState() {
            return mState;
        }


        public synchronized void start() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

            // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

            // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
            if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

            setState(STATE_LISTEN);

            // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
            if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
                mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
                mSecureAcceptThread.start();
            }
            if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
                mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
                mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
            }
        }


        public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);


            if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
                if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
            }


            if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}


            mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
            mConnectThread.start();
            setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
        }


        public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
                device, final String socketType) {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);


            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}


            if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}


            if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
                mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
                mSecureAcceptThread = null;
            }
            if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
                mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
                mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
            }


            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
            mConnectedThread.start();


            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(BTListDevice.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
        }


        public synchronized void stop() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            if (mConnectedThread != null) {
                mConnectedThread.cancel();
                mConnectedThread = null;
            }

            if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
                mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
                mSecureAcceptThread = null;
            }

            if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
                mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
                mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
            }
            setState(STATE_NONE);
        }


        public void write(byte[] out) {
            // Create temporary object
            ConnectedThread r;
            // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
                r = mConnectedThread;
            }
            // Perform the write unsynchronized
            r.write(out);
        }


        private void connectionFailed() {
            // Send a failure message back to the Activity
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(BTListDevice.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BTChatService.this.start();
        }


        private void connectionLost() {
            // Send a failure message back to the Activity
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(BTListDevice.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BTChatService.this.start();
        }

        private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
            // The local server socket
            private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
            private String mSocketType;

            public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
                BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
                mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

                // Create a new listening server socket
                try {
                    if (secure) {
                        tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                    } else {
                        tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                                NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
                }
                mmServerSocket = tmp;
            }

            public void run() {
                if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                        "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
                setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

                BluetoothSocket socket = null;

                // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
                while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    try {
                        // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                        // successful connection or an exception
                        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                        break;
                    }

                    // If a connection was accepted
                    if (socket != null) {
                        synchronized (BTChatService.this) {
                            switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                        mSocketType);
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

            }

            public void cancel() {
                if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
                }
            }
        }

        private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
            private String mSocketType;

            public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
                mmDevice = device;
                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
                mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

                // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
                // given BluetoothDevice
                try {
                    if (secure) {
                        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                                MY_UUID_SECURE);
                    } else {
                        tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                                MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
                }
                mmSocket = tmp;
            }

            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
                setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

                // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
                mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    mmSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Close the socket
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                                " socket during connection failure", e2);
                    }
                    connectionFailed();
                    return;
                }

                // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
                synchronized (BTChatService.this) {
                    mConnectThread = null;
                }

                // Start the connected thread
                connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
                }
            }
        }

            private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final InputStream mmInStream;
            private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
                Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
                mmSocket = socket;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
                }

                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }

            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes;

                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                        connectionLost();
                        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                        BTChatService.this.start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            public void write(byte[] buffer) {
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                    // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BTListDevice.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
                }
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### ChatActivity.java

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

```
ChatAdapter adapter;    
ListView chatList;
ChatDBHelper dbHelper;

public static String DEVICE_DET = "dev";

// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Message types sent from the BTChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BTChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

// Layout Views    
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

// Name of the connected device
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
// Array adapter for the conversation thread
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
// String buffer for outgoing messages
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
// Local Bluetooth adapter
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
// Member object for the chat services
private BTChatService mChatService = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.chat_layout);

    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chatTitle);
    final String device = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequence(DEVICE_DET);
    title.setText(device);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    dbHelper = new ChatDBHelper(this);

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }       

    chatList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor cur =  dbHelper.CTCheckEmpty(device);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    if(cur.getInt(0)>0)
    {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), device);
                chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });         
    }
    else
    {
        TextView empty = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        empty.setText("Start away Chatting! :)");       
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        chatList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count<=0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }       
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
         setupChat();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BTChatService.STATE_NONE) {
          // Start the Bluetooth chat services
          mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}

private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");        

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatBox);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatBox);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the BTChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BTChatService(this, mHandler);
    mChatService.start();

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
        BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}


private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BTChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }       

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BTChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);                                    

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final void setStatus(int resId) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}

private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
}

// The Handler that gets information back from the BTChatService
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        String device = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequence(DEVICE_DET);        
        Date today = new Date();
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat().format(today);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BTChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                //mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BTChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                setStatus("Connecting..");
                break;
            case BTChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BTChatService.STATE_NONE:
                setStatus("Not Connected..");
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:                
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;                
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);

                dbHelper.CTinsertData(device, 1, writeMessage, date, time);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                dbHelper.CTinsertData(device, 0, readMessage, date, time); 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectDevice(data, true);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectDevice(data, false);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
            setupChat();
        } else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, "BT Not Enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
    // Get the device MAC address
    String address = data.getExtras().getString("device_address");
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mChatService.connect(device, secure);
}
```

}

Comment: You discovered , what is the main cause of this behavior ?